# Docker compose bridge network

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, networking, docker-compose, bridge

I'm working on a project that has 2 docker compose files.
On one side I have my stack with a rails server.

```
version: '3'
  services:
    web:
      entrypoint: ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: <MY FILE>
        command: bundle exec rails s -b 'ssl://0.0.0.0?key=/app/ssl/server.key&cert=/app/ssl/server.crt'
       volumes:
         - .:/app
       ports:
         - "443:3000"
       stdin_open: true
       tty: true
       networks:
         - ekoma
networks:
  ekoma:
    driver: bridge
```

On the other side I have a wordpress instance

```
version: '3'
  services:
    wordpress:
      image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - 8888:80
    networks:
      - app_ekoma
networks:
  app_ekoma:
    external:
      name: app_ekoma
```

I am simplifying the compose files but I can provide more if needed.
For some reason, from my wordpress instance, I can use the "web" host and even launch a curl call:
`curl web:3000`

But the request hangs and does not finish.

It can also be a rails server issue but I am using it as an API and, from outside the network, I have no problem connecting to localhost:443.

Thanks for taking a look, any idea would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Does `https://web:3000` work better, up to TLS certificate errors?

Comment: Haha nice, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [User-defined Bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/#use-user-defined-bridge-networks) and then connect both of your containers to your bridge network.

To create the bridge:

```sh
>> docker network create --driver bridge my-user-defined-bridge-net
```

Then do a sanity check to see what's connected to it (nothing should be connected now):

```sh
>> docker network inspect my-user-defined-bridge-net
```

Scroll down a bit through the output until you see the Containers prop, which lists the connected containers. For now, it should be empty:

```json
"Containers": {}
```

Next, in each of your docker-compose files, connect the container to the bridge we just created.

Your first file would be:

```yaml
version: '3'
  services:
    web:
      container_name: container_one
      entrypoint: ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: <MY FILE>
        command: bundle exec rails s -b 'ssl://0.0.0.0?key=/app/ssl/server.key&cert=/app/ssl/server.crt'
       volumes:
         - .:/app
       ports:
         - "443:3000"
       stdin_open: true
       tty: true
       networks:
         - ekoma

networks:
  ekoma:
    external:
      name: my-user-defined-bridge-net
```

And your second file would be:

```yaml
version: '3'
  services:
    wordpress:
      container_name: container_two
      image: wordpress:latest
      ports:
        - 8888:80
      networks:
        - app_ekoma

networks:
  app_ekoma:
    external:
      name: my-user-defined-bridge-net
```

Restart both of your containers with these new docker-compose files and check the status of the bridge:

```sh
>> docker network inspect my-user-defined-bridge-net
```

The `"Containers"` prop should now show

```json
"Containers": {
            "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf1324654a1sd65fa56sdf": {
                "Name": "container_one",
                "EndpointID": "51asdf5sd651as65d1f1a65sdf1a63sd5f1asd65fa56sdf56asd6f5a65s1df",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1d:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.29.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "a6s51dfa65sd1fas6d5f1a6s5df0asd65f0a6sd5f41asd658f4sdf": {
                "Name": "container_two",
                "EndpointID": "6a5sdfa65sd1fa6s5df1as6d51fas6d51fa6s5d1f6a5sd16sd6a1s",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1d:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.29.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
```